# How to select the Telerik MVC TabStrip programatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

Does anyone know how to programatically switch tabs in the Telerik tabstrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you call Html.Telerik().TabStrip().SelectedIndex().

Check the [client-side api](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/clientsideapi) on their website for info on how to do it on the client.